# How to check type from any array having different enum types?

Tags: swift

I have an array of any Hashable type

`var navigationStack: [any Hashable] = []`

I am appending different enum types element in this array.

```
func append(_ value: any Hashable) {
    navigationStack.append(value)
}

struct MenuViewFactory {
    enum Options {
        case menu
    }
}

struct SleepViewFactory {
    enum Options {
        case sleep
    }
}

coordinator.append(MenuViewFactory.Options.menu)
coordinator.append(SleepViewFactory.Options.sleep)
```

For checking type of element, I have to type check elements from array.
I am having many enums of this type so type checking each and every enum is not better solution in this case.
I have tried checking it with hashValue, but in some cases it give same hashValue for different enums.

Does any one have any idea how to check without type checking to each and every enum type?

Comment: Hash values are unique within their type, but they are not guaranteed to be unique across all types.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's not working.

Comment: Did you try extending an enum with String and then providing unique values for each  cases? 

struct MenuViewFactory{
    enum Options: String {
        case menu = "1"
    }
}

Comment: You mean after providing unique values, It will provide unique hashValue?

Comment: Why do you put hashable values in your container, and not actual views or view factories?

Comment: @Yonat Yes I can append actual views in my container, but as this function is used in many places and in this function I am getting only enums. So this change will have a lot to do in many places.

Comment: This seems like a classic case to use polymorphism: Have all you views conform to a `protocol` with a `func doSomething()`, then just call this func for each element of the container. You don't need to know what type it is, because each element will automagically execute the correct actions for its type. (tell me if you want to see this clearly in code, and I'll submit this as an answer.)

Comment: @Yonat Could you please explain this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

What will you do after you get the type of the element? Probably execute some type-specific code, right?

Instead of having a big `switch` statement with the code for all types, it makes sense to keep the code for each type *in the type itself*. Just like every `UIView` has `draw()` func, but each one implements it differently.

So you first define a `protocol` with the function(s) you will want to call:

```swift
protocol MyView {
    func doSomething()
}
```

Then make your view classes implement this protocol:

```swift
class MenuView: UIView, MyView {
    func doSomething() {
        print("MenuView doing its thing")
    }
}

class SleepView: UIView, MyView {
    func doSomething() {
        print("SleepView doing a different thing")
    }
}
```

Now you can add `MyView` objects to a collection, and make them run code:

```swift
var navigationStack: [MyView] = []

navigationStack.append(MenuView())
navigationStack.append(SleepView())

for view in navigationStack {
    view.doSomething()
}

// Output:
//   MenuView doing its thing
//   SleepView doing a different thing
```

This is a basic OOP concept: Polymorphism. It's used everywhere in iOS and Swift (and other languages). It would be a good idea to learn and practice it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this will not work as I am having hundreds of classes and It's not good solution I think, to go and inherit from protocol in all classes.
Also the append function is called from multiple files and changing this will affect other changes also.
So I want to do some operation with this any Hashable type array that is the reason I was comparing Hashable values

Comment: What will you do after you get the type of the element? A big `switch` statement with hundreds of `case`s?